# Explicit central elements of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{so}(4,1))$

Tags: lie-algebras

I am interested in finding the central elements of the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$.

Notation: the 10 generators are $D, J_i, P_i, K_i$ ($i=1,2,3$), satisfying the commutation relations
$$ [J_l, J_m] = \epsilon_{lm}^{\:\:\:\:n} J_n, $$
$$ [J_l, P_m] = \epsilon_{lm}^{\:\:\:\:n} P_n, $$
$$ [P_j, D] = P_j, $$
$$ [D, K_j] = K_j, $$
$$ [P_l, K_m] = \delta_{lm}D + \epsilon_{lm}^{\:\:\:\:n}J_n, $$
$$ [J_l, K_m] = \epsilon_{lm}^{\:\:\:\:n} K_n, $$
and all other brackets zero (assume Einstein summation convention).

Clearly the quadratic Casimir is
$$ C_2 = D^2 - J^2 - \{P_j, K^j\}, $$
and there is also an independent (much more complicated) quartic Casimir $C_4$.

But what about other central elements? For example, we have the identities
$$ \{K_2, P_1\} - \{P_2, K_1\} = \{D, J_3\} $$
(+ cyc. perm.) and
$$ \{K_j, J^j\} = \{P_j, J^j\} = 0.$$
So for quadratic elements I find 6 relations in total.

Now [1] says that the space of symmetric quadratic elements of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{so}(4,1))$ is 35 dimensional, but with 20 linear relations between them that reduces the dimension to 15. However [2] gives the expected $55 = {10\choose2} + 10$ dimensions. In any case, I can't see how to find 14 more linear relations.

Is there an established procedure for finding central elements of (quadratic elements of) a universal enveloping algebra? [3] gives a method for $\mathcal{U}_q(\mathfrak{so}(5))$ but I am unfamiliar with quantum algebras and don't know how to extend this to my case.

This question is coming from a physicist's perspective so apologies if I am unfamiliar with existing notation/literature.

[1] C. P. Boyer, E. G. Kalnins, and W. Miller, Jr., Symmetry and separation of variables for the Helmholtz and Laplace equations, https://doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000017165

[2] Michael Eastwood, Higher symmetries of the Laplacian, https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2005.161.1645

[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.19156

Comment: For an absolutely simple real Lie algebra (i.e. its complexification is simple) there is only a single quadratic central element up to scale. The whole dimension of the centre is equal to the rank of the Lie algebra so for $\mathfrak{so(4,1)}$ it is 2-dimensional and the quadratic element plus the quartic one span the whole centre. Getting explicit basis elements for the centre in general can be done using the [Harish-Chandra isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism), I believe.

Comment: It looks like I might be confusing $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{so}(4,1))$ with the algebra of (higher) symmetries of the Laplacian. Why are there additional relations between quadratic elements in the latter algebra but not the former?

Comment: Skimming through that paper by Eastwood, there are no requirements for the symmetries for the Laplacian to be central. Instead they are elements of a quotient of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{so}(4,1))$ (note: be careful assuming that centre of the quotient is neatly related to the centre of the original algebra). The additional relations you talk of are, I think, precisely the quotient relations as described in Theorem 3 of that paper.

Comment: Ok I see I really didn't read/understand far enough into the Eastwood paper! What I'm struggling with are the different kinds of tensor product used in the statement(s) of Thm 3. What are $\odot$ and $\circledcirc$? Can't everything just be spelled out explicitly in terms of $\otimes$? For my application I ultimately just need differential operators, but I'd like to use these results to simplify my calculations.